# Probability of $4$-game winning streak among $8$ basketball games

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> My basketball team has eight games next month. We're pretty good; we have a ${2\over3}$ chance to win in each game. What is the probability we have a winning streak of at least four games at some point during the month?

Here's what I did:

$8$ in a row:

- WWWWWWWW: $\left({2\over3}\right)^8$

$7$ in a row:

- LWWWWWWW, WWWWWWWL: $2\left({2\over3}\right)^7\left({1\over3}\right)$

$6$ in a row:

- LLWWWWWW, LWWWWWWL, WWWWWWLL: $3\left({2\over3}\right)^6\left({1\over3}\right)^2$
- WLWWWWWW, WWWWWWLW: $2\left({2\over3}\right)^7\left({1\over3}\right)$

$5$ in a row:

- LLLWWWWW, LLWWWWWL, LWWWWWLL, WWWWWLLL: $4\left({2\over3}\right)^5\left({1\over3}\right)^3$
- WWWWWLWL, WWWWWLLW, LWWWWWLW, LWLWWWW, WLLWWWWW, WLWWWWWL: $6\left({2\over3}\right)^6\left({1\over3}\right)^2$
- WWWWWLWW, WWLWWWWW: $2\left({2\over3}\right)^7\left({1\over3}\right)$

$4$ in a row:

- WWWWLLLL, LWWWWLLL, LLWWWWLL, LLLWWWWL, LLLLWWWW: $5\left({2\over3}\right)^4\left({1\over3}\right)^4$
- $2\times$: WWWWLWLL, WWWWLLWL, WWWWLLLW, LLWWWWLW, LWWWWLWL, LWWWWLLW: $12\left({2\over3}\right)^5\left({1\over3}\right)^3$
- WWWWLWWL, WWLWWWWL, LWWLWWWW, LWWWWLWW, WWWWLLWW, WWLLWWWW: $6\left({2\over3}\right)^6\left({1\over3}\right)^2$
- WWWLWWWW, WWWWLWWW: $2\left({2\over3}\right)^7\left({1\over3}\right)$

Adding these all up and reducing, I get ${{944}\over{2187}}$.

However, at this [link](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/my-basketball-team-has-eight-games-next-month-we-re-pretty-good-we-have-a-2-3-chance-to-win-in-each-game-what-is-the-probability-we-have) Melody ended up getting ${{112}\over{243}}$ as the answer to this problem. Who is correct, and if Melody at the aforelinked is correct, then where specifically did I count wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed 3 cases where there are 6 wins with 4 in a row: WWWWLWLW, WLWLWWWW, WLWWWWLW. Then we have that
$$p=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8+8\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+18\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+
16\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3+5\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4=\frac{112}{243}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good answer, but here is an alternative approach in case you're interested.  We develop a recursive solution, which involves fewer cases than those seen so far and has the advantage that it is easy to extend to more than $8$ games.

We consider the complementary problem: What is the probability of a series of $8$ games in which there is no string of $4$ wins in a row?

Let's say $a_{n,m}$ is the probability of playing $n$ games with no instance of $4$ wins in a row in which the series of $n$ games ends in a sequence of $m$ wins, for $0 \le m \le 3$.  We have $a_{1,0} = 1/3$, $a_{1,1} = 2/3$, and $a_{1,2} =a_{1,3} = 0$.  For $n>1$, we end up in state $(n,0)$ any time the $n$th game is a loss, so
$$a_{n,0} = (1/3)(a_{n-1,0} + a_{n-1,1} + a_{n-1,2} + a_{n-1,3})$$
To get to state $(n,m)$ for $m > 0$ we must have a series of $n-1$ games ending in $m-1$ wins, followed by a win, so
$$a_{n,m} = (2/3) a_{n-1,m-1}$$ for $1 \le m \le 3$.

We can use this recursion to calculate $a_{n,m}$ for values of $n$ as large as we please.  Here are the values for $1 \le n \le 8$, in which the columns correspond to $m=0,1,2,3$, working to $4$ decimal places:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
1&0.3333 &0.6667 &0.0000 &0.0000\\
2&0.3333 &0.2222 &0.4444 &0.0000\\
3&0.3333 &0.2222 &0.1481 &0.2963\\
4&0.3333 &0.2222 &0.1481 &0.0988\\
5&0.2675 &0.2222 &0.1481 &0.0988\\
6&0.2455 &0.1783 &0.1481 &0.0988\\
7&0.2236 &0.1637 &0.1189 &0.0988\\
8&0.2016 &0.1491 &0.1091 &0.0793
\end{array}$$

(A spreadsheet makes for easy calculation.)
The probability of a series of $8$ games with no series of $4$ wins in a row is
$$\sum_{m=0}^3 a_{8,m} = 0.5391$$ so the probability of having at least $4$ wins in a row is $1-0.5391 = \boxed{0.4609}$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Notice that to win four in a row, the winning streak must begin in one of the first five games.  Let $A_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$, be the set of outcomes in which your team wins four consecutive games starting with the $i$th match.  Then, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the probability that your team wins at least four consecutive matches in the next month is
\begin{align*}
& \Pr(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4 \cup A_5)\\ 
& \qquad = \sum_{i = 1}^5 \Pr(A_i) - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq 5} \Pr(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq 5} \Pr(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k)\\
& \qquad \qquad - \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k < l \leq 5}\Pr(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l) + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5|
\end{align*}

$\Pr(A_1)$:  The probability that your team wins the first four games is
$$\Pr(A_1) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4$$
since your team wins or loses the remaining four games with probability $1$.

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1) = \Pr(A_2) = \Pr(A_3) = \Pr(A_4) = \Pr(A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2)$:  If your team wins the first four games and wins games two through five, then it must win the first five games.  The probability that your team wins the first five games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3) = \Pr(A_3 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_3)$:  If your team wins the first four games and wins games three through six, then your team must win the first six games.  The probability that your team wins the first six games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_3) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_3) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_3 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_4)$:  If your team wins the first four games and wins games four through seven, then it must win the first seven games.  The probability that your team wins the first seven games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_4) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_5)$:  If your team wins the first four games and the last four games, then it must win all eight games.  The probability that your team wins all eight games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_5) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, and games three through six, then it must win the first six games.  The probability that your team wins the first six games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, and games four through seven, then it must win the first seven games.  The probability that your team wins the first seven games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_5)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, and the last four games, it must win all eight games.  The probability that your team wins all eight games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_5) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_5) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_5) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, games three through six, and games four through seven, it must win the first seven games.   The probability that your team wins the first seven games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4) = \Pr(A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, games three through six, and the last four games, then it must win all eight games.  The probability that your team wins all eight games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8$$

By symmetry,
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_5) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) = \Pr(A_1 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$$

$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$:  If your team wins the first four games, games two through five, games three through six, games four through seven, and the last four games, it must win all eight games.  The probability that your team wins all eight games is
$$\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8$$

Thus, the probability that your team wins at least four consecutive games next month is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5) & = 5\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\\  
& \qquad - 4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5 - 3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6 - 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8\\
& \quad\qquad + 3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6 + 4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7 + 3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8\\
& \qquad\qquad - 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^7 - 3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8\\
& \quad\qquad\qquad + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^8\\
& = 5\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4 - 4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5\\
& = 5\left(\frac{16}{81}\right) - 4\left(\frac{32}{243}\right)\\
& = \frac{80}{81} - \frac{128}{243}\\
& = \frac{240}{243} - \frac{128}{243}\\
& = \frac{112}{243}
\end{align*}